# Something wrong with my PollardP1_rho code but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, prime-factoring

I tried to use MillerRabin + PollardP1_rho method to factorize an integer into primes in Python3 for reducing time complexity as much as I could.But it failed some tests,I knew where the problem was.But I am a tyro in algorithm, I didn't know how to fix it.So I will put all relative codes here.

```
import random

def gcd(a, b):
    """
    a, b: integers
    returns: a positive integer, the greatest common divisor of a & b.
    """
    if a == 0:
        return b
    if a < 0:
        return gcd(-a, b)
    while b > 0:
        c = a % b
        a, b = b, c
    return a

def mod_mul(a, b, n):
    # Calculate a * b % n iterately.
    result = 0
    while b > 0:
        if (b & 1) > 0:
            result = (result + a) % n
        a = (a + a) % n
        b = (b >> 1)
    return result

def mod_exp(a, b, n):
    # Calculate (a ** b) % n iterately.
    result = 1
    while b > 0:
        if (b & 1) > 0:
            result = mod_mul(result, a, n)
        a = mod_mul(a, a, n)
        b = (b >> 1)
    return result

def MillerRabinPrimeCheck(n):
    if n in {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}:
        return True
    elif (n == 1 or n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0 or n % 7 == 0 or n % 11 == 0):
        return False
    k = 0
    u = n - 1
    while not (u & 1) > 0:
        k += 1
        u = (u >> 1)
    random.seed(0)
    s = 5 #If the result isn't right, then add the var s.
    for i in range(s):
        x = random.randint(2, n - 1)
        if x % n == 0:
            continue
        x = mod_exp(x, u, n)
        pre = x
        for j in range(k):
            x = mod_mul(x, x, n)
            if (x == 1 and pre != 1 and pre != n - 1):
                return False
            pre = x
        if x != 1:
            return False
        return True

def PollardP1_rho(n, c):
    '''
    Consider c as a constant integer.
    ''' 
    i = 1
    k = 2
    x = random.randrange(1, n - 1) + 1
    y = x
    while 1:
        i += 1
        x = (mod_mul(x, x, n) + c) % n
        d = gcd(y - x, n)
        if 1 < d < n:
            return d
        elif x == y:
            return n
        elif i == k:
            y = x
            k = (k << 1)

result = []
def PrimeFactorsListGenerator(n):
    if n <= 1:
        pass
    elif MillerRabinPrimeCheck(n) == True:
        result.append(n)
    else:
        a = n
        while a == n:
            a = PollardP1_rho(n, random.randrange(1,n - 1) + 1)
        PrimeFactorsListGenerator(a)
        PrimeFactorsListGenerator(n // a)
```

When I tried to test this:

```
PrimeFactorsListGenerator(4)
```

It didn't stop and looped this:

```
PollardP1_rho(4, random.randrange(1,4 - 1) + 1)
```

I have already tested the functions before PollardP1_rho and they work normally,so I know the function PollardP1_rho cannot deal the number 4 correctly,also the number 5.How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself.
There is 1 mistake in the code.
I should not use a var 'result' outside of the function as a global var,I should define in the function and use result.extend() to ensure the availability of the whole recursive process.So I rewrote PollardP1_rho(n, c) and PrimeFactorsListGenerator(n):

```
def Pollard_rho(x, c):
    '''
    Consider c as a constant integer.
    ''' 
    i, k = 1, 2
    x0 = random.randint(0, x)
    y = x0
    while 1:
        i += 1
        x0 = (mod_mul(x0, x0, x) + c) % x
        d = gcd(y - x0, x)
        if d != 1 and d != x:
            return d
        if y == x0:
            return x
        if i == k:
            y = x0
            k += k

def PrimeFactorsListGenerator(n):
    result = []
    if n <= 1:
        return None
    if MillerRabinPrimeCheck(n):
        return [n]
    p = n
    while p >= n:
        p = Pollard_rho(p, random.randint(1, n - 1))
    result.extend(PrimeFactorsListGenerator(p))
    result.extend(PrimeFactorsListGenerator(n // p))
    return result

#PrimeFactorsListGenerator(400)
#PrimeFactorsListGenerator(40000)
```

**There is an additional tip**: You don't need to write a function mod_mul(a, b, n) at all, using Python built-in pow(a, b, n) will do the trick and it is fully optimized.